# Video with drop frames with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am recording videos using ffmpeg in a production environment almost non-stop for 15 hours a day. Sometimes the videos are freezing for a few seconds.

I believe the hardware is adequate. It is an  i7 with 16GB ram and windows 10. The videos are on average about 2:00 minute each.

This happens a few times a day 10 or so that I am awarded.

Here is a link to one of the videos that froze:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q6R2l1AkCko-uh2KZ6X8AChdGU5XBOy7

It freezes at 0:03 and then restarts at 0:16

Here is the ffmpeg command I am using:

ffmpeg  -i "rtsp://10.0.131.2/media/video1" -f segment -segment_time 9000 -segment_format mp4 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 -c copy -map 0 gabe.mp4

Can I decreases the quality of the videos so videos don't randomly freeze?

Would recording without audio help the videos not randomly freeze?

Thanks,

Gabe

Comment: Need to see ffmpeg log of a video that freezes.